# In C++, what's the difference between a literal 3 and the result of de-referencing a variable with a value 3?

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

We know that if I have a variable `int a{3}`, I can get `a`'s address by `&a`. And I can get the the address `&a`'s pointed value by `*&a`, which returns the integer `3`. So right now we already got the number `3`, we can't do something like `&3` to get the literal's address as that will generate an error. But the problem is that we can successfully using something like `*&*&a` to get the value `3` back. As I stated, `*&a` already returns a number `3` and you can't continue the chain on it. Why it works when writing as `*&*&a`?

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category

Comment: You're confusing `&` as indicating a reference with the address-of operator.

Comment: specifically, the [literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue) `3` is a "prvalue" while [dereferencing a pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_indirection_operator) yields an "lvalue"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a significant difference in between using a literal and using a variable on machine code (or assembler) level:

Typically, the literal can be encoded in machine code directly, whereas it might be necessary to load the value of another variable from memory first, if a such one is involved.

Actually, your variant `int b = *&a;` is quite close to what a pure load/store architecture (lacking any kind of indirect addressing) would need to do (assuming both variables are located in memory, 0xadda being address of variable `a`, 0xdaad the one of variable `b`):

```
MOV Rx, ADDA; // move address of a into some register
LD  Ry, Rx;   // load value at address in register into a second one
              // (maybe there's a direct addressing mode, then both operations
              // could be a single one)
MOV Rx, DAAD;
ST  Rx, Ry;
```

In comparison, `int b = 3;` is a bit simpler on the same machine:

```
MOV Rx, DAAD;
MOV Ry, 3;    // 3 directly encoded in bit pattern
ST  Rx, Ry;
```

OK, maybe you have some appropriate addressing mode, such that `int b = a;` *can* be encoded in one single instruction:

```
MOV #DAAD, #ADDA // # indicating indirect access via address
```

Still you cannot discuss away that there's an additional memory access necessary comparing to using the literal...

Perhaps even more interesting for you: How would you want to get the address of some value being 'mystically' encoded in some bit pattern of some machine code command (the `&3` part)?